# Excel Date calculation and comparison not returning expected result

Tags: excel

Project Plan is in Excel. Goal is fixing Status Field

I understand that this is probably not the most efficient way to do this.. I am automating the "Status" of project tasks. The Function contains nested IF and AND components.

O7=Phase ; There are 4 Phases and each change when the item moves from On Time to At Risk to Overtime

H7 is the Planned End Date (date field in Excel), which is compared to TODAY() to see if the the value falls within the parameters set in the function.

Here is the Function:

```
=
IF(AND(O7=1,TODAY()-H7<=0),"On Time",
IF(AND(O7=1,0<TODAY()-H7<6),"At Risk",
IF(AND(O7=1,TODAY()-H7>5),"Overdue",
IF(AND(O7=2,TODAY()-H7<=0),"On Time",
IF(AND(O7=2,0<TODAY()-H7<8),"At Risk",
IF(AND(O7=2,TODAY()-H7>7),"Overdue",
IF(AND(O7=3,TODAY()-H7<=0),"On Time",
IF(AND(O7=3,0<TODAY()-H7<11),"At Risk",
IF(AND(O7=3,TODAY()-H7>10),"Overdue",
IF(AND(O7=4,TODAY()-H7<=0),"On Time",
IF(AND(O7=4,0<TODAY()-H7<21),"At Risk",
IF(AND(O7=4,TODAY()-H7>20),"Overdue"))))))))))))
```

Here is the problem:

```
IF(AND(O7=1,0<TODAY()-H7<6),"At Risk",
```

I am unable to get my cell to display "At Risk" when I know for sure that TODAY()-H7=4. Am I missing something syntax related that is preventing this middle case from working?

Literally any guidance, either following this model or introducing a new way, will be helpful!

Comment: problem is here `0<TODAY()-H7<6` you are subtracting the result of two comparision do `AND(0<(TODAY()-H7),(TODAY()-H7)<6)` and it should work.

Comment: look at my answer, you can improve your formula. you are checking for lots of unnecessary conditions..

Comment: Another option for the future (and other users) when you have ranges that are used to calculate a category is to do a create a second table that lists the first value in the range with its category beside it. Then use a VLOOKUP with an Appx match and it will automatically categorize it for you. It eliminates the need for OP's IF statement. Note that in his case, he had two conditions in his statement, so you would need a different table depending on which of the first condition you are in.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to start, you seem to have no idea about if-else. When the if condition is false then you don't have to check it again, for example:

```
IF(AND(O7=1,TODAY()-H7<=0),"On Time",
IF(AND(O7=1,0<TODAY()-H7<6),"At Risk",
```

here in second line, the difference is already >0, if not it;d have been "On Time" already. you don't have to check it exclusively.
Immediate solution would be to make it `(TODAY()-H7)<6`. But you can also do some more reformatting of the formula.

```
IF(O7=1,IF((TODAY()-H7)<=0,"On Time",(TODAY()-H7)<6,"At Risk","Over Due"),
IF(O7=2,IF((TODAY()-H7)<=0,"On Time",(TODAY()-H7)<8,"At Risk","Over Due"),
IF(O7=3,IF((TODAY()-H7)<=0,"On Time",(TODAY()-H7)<11,"At Risk","Over Due"),
IF(O7=4,IF((TODAY()-H7)<=0,"On Time",(TODAY()-H7)<21,"At Risk","Over Due"),"N/A"))))
```

You can even store the time (6,8,11,21) with O7 values (1,2,3,4) so you can use that to make even shorter formula.